# Express can I use fast-json-stringify instead of express.json?

Tags: node.js, express

JSON fast stringify is very fast and I want to ask you can I replace the middleware express.json for json-fast-stringify/fast json parse?

If yes how can I do it with middleware ?

Ps: I saw some benchmark where the improvements is very good when anyone using json fast stringify or fast json (parse)

Comment: Yes, you can use it in middleware, but you would have to write your own middleware (or find one someone else has written) to do it because `express.json()` does not have a configuration option to supply your own parser.  You can go look at the code for `express.json()`, copy it and substitute in your own parser.  It's all open source.  Before doing that work, I'd write some tests to find out if its really worth it or not.  This will only be in play on requests that send your server JSON.